# How should I structure the URL of a RESTful API operation which returns 'recent' values?

Tags: json, rest, asp.net-web-api

Consider a RESTful API which provides information about transactions which are related to people.

```
[
  {
    amount: 12
    date: "2019-01-01"
  },
  {
    amount: 5
    date: "2019-02-01"
  }
]
```

I want functionality for the following use cases: 
- List transactions (with filters such as start date and end date), 
- List recent transactions (optionally specifying number of months into the past).

My proposed URL structure is as follows:

```
// Normal
GET v1/persons/{personId}/transactions?startDate={startDate}&endDate={endDate}

// Recent 
GET v1/persons/{personId}/transactions/recent?months={months}
```

However, I'm concious that the second URL doesn't confirm to REST conventions, as it is:

- not idempotent
- not actually a resource

What is the correct way (if any) to structure this URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not idempotent

That's not what idempotent means; see [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2), which defines precisely what is meant by idempotent semantics in HTTP.

In short, resources aren't idempotent or not; idempotent describes the semantics of message handling.  It is common for resources to support some requests that are safe, some that idempotent but not safe, and some that are neither.

> not actually a resource

That's not what resource means.  Here's what [Fielding wrote](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1):

> Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource. A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities, not the entity that corresponds to the mapping at any particular point in time.

"Recent transactions" is certainly a resource; that's true even though its representations may change over time.

> I'm conscious that the second URL doesn't confirm to REST conventions

The only real convention that you missed is the leading slash in the target uri!  There are a number of forms that the request-target can take in an HTTP request line, but for the purposes of accessing a resource you want the [origin-form](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.1), which must start with a [U+002F SOLIDUS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2f/index.htm)

```
/v1/persons/12345/transactions/recent?months=6
```

Is a perfectly fine identifier for a resource.